# tmap + labels colors don't match the data

Tags: r, polygon, spatial-database, tmap

I created the following map. However, the labels in the legend don't match the data. I don't understand what goes wrong. I expected the pal colors to be ordered with the labels. So would do the data.

Example= no drought color would normally correspond to the severe drought cells on the map.

Here is a sample of my data

```
structure(list(gid = c(100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 
100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100468L, 100475L, 100475L, 
100475L, 100475L, 100475L, 100475L, 100475L, 100475L, 100475L, 
100475L), country = c("Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", 
"Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia", "Namibia"), total_conflicts = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Year = c(2005, 
2003, 2009, 2007, 2008, 2001, 2006, 1999, 2002, 2004, 1997, 2009, 
2007, 2010, 2000, 2008, 2006, 1999, 2005, 2004), ycoord = c(-20.25, 
-20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, 
-20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, -20.25, 
-20.25, -20.25, -20.25), xcoord = c(13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 
13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 13.75, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 
17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25, 17.25), VCI = c(38.4215158606475, 
33.233853670267, 66.8255937282856, 45.530642912938, 47.6116253045889, 
43.6939180080707, 71.3801674476037, 16.7028192006625, 49.7771763434777, 
29.5257619689493, 58.5738585178669, 67.0596055250901, 41.2335995894212, 
60.8284931916457, 41.6004944466628, 55.5477022024301, 77.3257617216844, 
13.382687486135, 37.1140933306712, 39.0084276199341), vcidrought = c(1, 
1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1), vcidrought_type = structure(c(2L, 
2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("Extreme drought", "Mild drought", "Moderate drought", 
"No drought", "Severe drought"), class = "factor"), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, -20.5, 
    -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 
    13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L
    ))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 
    14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 
    13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L
    ))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 
    14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 13.5, 14, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(14, 14, 13.5, 
    13.5, 14, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L
    ))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 
    17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 
    17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 
    17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(
        structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, 
        -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", 
    "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 17, 17, 17.5, 
    -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 2L))), class = c("XY", 
    "POLYGON", "sfg")), structure(list(structure(c(17.5, 17.5, 
    17, 17, 17.5, -20.5, -20, -20, -20.5, -20.5), .Dim = c(5L, 
    2L))), class = c("XY", "POLYGON", "sfg"))), class = c("sfc_POLYGON", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = 13.5, ymin = -20.5, 
xmax = 17.5, ymax = -20), class = "bbox"), crs = structure(list(
    input = "WGS 84", wkt = "GEOGCRS[\"WGS 84\",\n    DATUM[\"World Geodetic System 1984\",\n        ELLIPSOID[\"WGS 84\",6378137,298.257223563,\n            LENGTHUNIT[\"metre\",1]]],\n    PRIMEM[\"Greenwich\",0,\n        ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    CS[ellipsoidal,2],\n        AXIS[\"latitude\",north,\n            ORDER[1],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n        AXIS[\"longitude\",east,\n            ORDER[2],\n            ANGLEUNIT[\"degree\",0.0174532925199433]],\n    ID[\"EPSG\",4326]]"), class = "crs"), n_empty = 0L)), row.names = c(8L, 
10L, 11L, 13L, 14L, 15L, 16L, 17L, 20L, 21L, 216L, 220L, 222L, 
225L, 227L, 229L, 230L, 235L, 236L, 237L), class = c("sf", "data.frame"
), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(gid = NA_integer_, 
country = NA_integer_, total_conflicts = NA_integer_, Year = NA_integer_, 
ycoord = NA_integer_, xcoord = NA_integer_, VCI = NA_integer_, 
vcidrought = NA_integer_, vcidrought_type = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"))
```

Here is my code:

```
labels = c("No drought", "Mild drought", "Moderate drought", 
           "Severe drought", "Extreme drought")

tm_shape(test) + 
  tm_polygons(col="vcidrought_type",
          pal =c("#5DC863FF", "#21908CFF", "#3B528BFF", "#440154FF", "#000004FF"),
          labels = labels,
          title="Drought types") +
  tm_layout(main.title = "VCI drought type in Sub-Saharan Africa 1997-2010", 
            main.title.position = "center", frame= FALSE) +
  tm_shape(shp_union) +
  tm_symbols(col = "red", border.col = "white", size = "total_conflicts")
```

[image]

Comment: You need to set your levels order for the test$vcidrought_type vector (change it from character to factor). See, e.g., https://swcarpentry.github.io/r-novice-inflammation/12-supp-factors/index.html.

Comment: It's already on factor.

Comment: I have found an answer in this related post on stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73983685/tmap-labels-colors-dont-match-the-data?noredirect=1#comment130631268_73983685

Answer (score 1):

Instead of labels, class = factor you may want to code the classifications as levels.

```
levels(data) <- c("No drought", "Mild drought", "Moderate drought", 
           "Severe drought", "Extreme drought")
```